# how to calculate the time of the open ticket with regard to working hours in php

Tags: php

Somehow I need calcute the time of the open ticket with regard to working hours & weekends. For example I have opened ticket time 2016-07-28 16:15, working hours is from 08:00 to 17:00. Have anyone ideas how to write this in php code?

Comment: Loop through days and calculate included working days. Start from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Or use DateTime::diff() then subtract weekend and non-working hours.